# C++ how to check for all variadic template type in a member function

Tags: c++

e.g. I have the following Foo class with the foo() to check if all the types are std::int32_t

```
class Foo {
public:
    /// check if all the types are std::int32_t
    template<typename ...Ts>
    bool foo() {
        return true && std::is_same<Ts, std::int32_t>::value...;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout<<f.template foo<std::int32_t, std::int32_t>(); //true
    std::cout<<f.template foo<std::int32_t, std::int64_t>(); //false

    return 0;
}
```

`return true && std::is_same<Ts, std::int32_t>::value...;` is not a correct syntax. How do I make it correct?

Comment: FYI, the `.template` is unnecessary here since you are not in a deduced context. Also, doing this as a member function is a little weird, a templated constant makes more sense at face value: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GY7acoTqq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

```
return (true && ... && std::is_same<Ts, std::int32_t>::value);
# or
return (std::is_same<Ts, std::int32_t>::value && ... && true);
# or really just
return (std::is_same<Ts, std::int32_t>::value && ...);
```

Comment: I think the `&& true` is redundant in that fold expression?

Comment: Cleaner still: `return (std::is_same_v<Ts, std::int32_t> && ...);`